# Como usar Application Insights em mais de uma aplicação?

Tags: microsoft-azure, application-insights

É possível utilizar o **Application Insights** em mais de uma aplicação e no Azure eu ter como filtrar os dados de cada aplicação separadamente ?

Comment: Qual problema vc quer resolver usando um serivço de App Insights para multiplas aplicações?

Comment: Separa as informações de cada aplicação no app Insights.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> É possível utilizar o Application Insights em mais de uma aplicação?

**SIM!** Não existe nenhuma restrição quanto a isso. É até comum usarem um unico serviço para métricas de backend - API - e clientes - WEB, Mobile, etc. Mas, nao é muito fácil de gerir isso depois.

> ... e no Azure eu ter como filtrar os dados de cada aplicação separadamente?

Exatamente aqui é o problema, se tudo for parte se um mesmo software - backend, client mobile - ate dá para considerar. Mas sendo sistema diferentes, além de não ser fácil de depois separar, não há motivos para fazer isso.

Para conseguir filtrar, vc pode adicionar um `ITelemetryProcessor` para interceptar os *trackings*.

```
public class MeuFiltroTelemetryProcessor : ITelemetryProcessor
{
    private ITelemetryProcessor Next { get; set; }

    public MeuFiltroProcessor(ITelemetryProcessor next)
    {
        Next = next;
    }

    public void Process(ITelemetry item)
    {
        var request = item as RequestTelemetry;
        if (request == null)
        {
            Next.Process(item);
            return;
        }

        if (request.VeioDoBackend())
        {
            request.Context.Properties["Backend"] = "true";
        }
        else if (request.VeioDoWebsite())
        {
            request.Context.Properties["Website"] = "true";
        }
        else if (request.VeioDoMobileApp())
        {
            request.Context.Properties["MobileApp"] = "true";
        }

        Next.Process(item);
    }
}
```

Depois basta adicionar seu processador ao serviço principal:

```
var builder = TelemetryConfiguration.Active.TelemetryProcessorChainBuilder;
builder.Use(next => new MeuFiltroTelemetryProcessor(next));
builder.Build();
```

Agora, via portal do AppInsights, basta filtrar por `Backend`, `WebSite` ou `MobileApp`.

Não há custo ter inúmeros serviços de AppInsights. Os planos atuais apenas começam a te cobrar após alguns Giga de bigdata armazenados, o que pode levar muito tempo. Se vc compartilha o serviço, irá atingir essa linha de início de cobrança mais rapidamente, quando se tiver um serviço por app, será bem mais dificil de cruzar esse limite.

Comment: Legal Thiago, vou avaliar e ver como resolver, depois volto para dar o aceite.

Comment: Ok @MarconcilioSouza

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza adicionei um exemplo de código. Veja se melhora a resposta.

Comment: Thiago, não entendi exatamente o que seria (basta adicionar seu processador ao serviço principal), desculpa, mas novo nesse assunto. Se tive como detalha mais seria lega,l até porque não tem muito conteúdo sobre esse assunto no SO-PT.

Comment: Veja detalhes aqui: [Filtrando e pré-processando a telemetria no SDK do Application Insights](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/azure/application-insights/app-insights-api-filtering-sampling#a-namefiltering-itelemetryprocessorafiltragem-itelemetryprocessor)

Comment: Qdo vc adiciona o AppInsights na sua aplicação, ele tem um configurador `TelemetryConfiguration`. É um configurador global. Basta adicionar seu processador `MeuFiltroTelemetryProcessor` nele a cada tracking, irá chamar seu filtro.

Comment: Cara você chegou exatamente onde eu queria, vlw mesmo.